# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to make a simple chrome extension which adds an `<input>` element to the active tab when an option ('Add an input box') from the context menu (right-click menu) is clicked.

Here is the background.js file.

```
//background.js

function createNewInput(info, tab){
   let input=document.createElement("input");
   input.style.position="fixed";
   input.style.left=0;
   input.style.top=0;
   input.style.width="100px";
   input.style.height="100px";
   input.style.background="green";
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: "document.body.appendChild(" + input + ");"
   });
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
   "onclick": createNewInput,
   "title": "Add an input box"
});
```

And here is the manifest.json file

```
//manifest.json
{
   "manifest_version" : 2,
   "name": "Test",
   "version": "0.1",
   "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
   },
   "permissions": [
      "contextMenus",
      "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

I get *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier* error in the console window (of the page where I try to create) when I try to create a new input from the context menu option.

Things I have already tried

1. Adding the `<input>` manually using the same code in the dev tools console window. (Works)
   [image: code]
   [image: result]
2. Checking for any invisible characters (zero width spaces like unicode U+200b). There are none.
3. Checking for lint issues. There seem to be none.

Comment: Indeed, `document.body.appendChild([Object HTMLInputElement])` is invalid syntax.

Comment: `code: "document.body.appendChild(" + input + ");"` is the issue

Comment: You can't stringify DOM elements. Put the entire code that creates the element inside a string that you run in executeScript.

Comment: @elegant-user That will not work: `appendChild` takes a HTML Element as argument, but `input.outerHTML` is a string. Better follow @wOxxOm's instructions.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions! Helped a lot. :)